# SSL error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku

My rails app (Rails 4.0, Ruby 2.0.) has a rake task that when run remotely on Heroku results in the error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: (null)
```

The offending code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(item.link))
```

I tried adding:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(item.link, ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE))
```

This doesn't cange anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175151/connecting-using-https-to-a-server-with-a-certificate-signed-by-a-ca-i-created

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, spesifically adding: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = 'SSLv3'