# SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A - Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I've seen many answers here, but none of them has worked.

I'm using [omniauth-oauth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2) to integrate with a third-party customer.

I'm using the setup phase described [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase) but I'm always getting this error:

```
Authentication failure! failed_to_connect: Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed, SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed (SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3     read server hello A):
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
```

My initializer at `config/initializers` is:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  client_id = 'my_client_id'
  client_secret = 'secret'

  ca_file = Rails.root.join('config', 'cacert.pem').to_s

  ssl_options = {}
  ssl_options[:ca_path] = '/usr/local/etc/openssl'
  ssl_options[:ca_file] = ca_file

  provider :my_partner_provider, client_id, client_secret,  :client_options => {:ssl => ssl_options},
    setup: ->(env){
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    site = "https://#{req.params.fetch('shop')}"
    env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site]  = site
  }
end
```

I've tried with and without ssl options.

To complement, here's my stack: https://gist.github.com/cleytonmessias/11274209

I've typed in terminal `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect partnerurl.com:443 <<<OK` and it returned this: https://gist.github.com/cleytonmessias/11288646

Does anyone know the solution to this issue?

Comment: I'd say this is a bug, but it probably doesn't come from Net::HTTP. I had this issue when connecting to Sharepoint services: wget was also unable to connect, whereas curl had no issue at all.

Comment: But did you solved? I still didn't find anything.

Comment: What OpenSSL version are you using? And is it the system one or the one that comes with RVM?

Comment: Also make sure you're pointing to the right port on the service

Comment: I'm om Mavericks.
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014 | 
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl"

Comment: Try removing the ssl options on the initializers and adding the gem 'certified' to the gemfile. Also remember to restart the server after the bundle.

Comment: @GonzaloS I've done and still got the same error =/

Comment: This is a longshot, but, why don't you use nitrous.io and discard taht the problem is your computer.

Comment: No way, we're a team and it must work in everyones machine

Comment: Does explicitly setting `ssl_version` help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9262269

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @mislav who give the hint to change [`SSL version`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175151/connecting-using-https-to-a-server-with-a-certificate-signed-by-a-ca-i-created/9262269#9262269).

I had to change this because my partner has its application built using asp.net and uses this version of SSL. More info at https://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/

So the final code is as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  client_id = 'my_client_id'
  client_secret = 'secret'

  ssl_options = {}
  ssl_options[:version] = :TLSv1

  ssl = {}
  ssl[:ssl] =  ssl_options

  provider :partner, client_id, client_secret,
    client_options: { connection_opts: ssl} ,
    setup: ->(env){
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    token_url = "https://#{req.params.fetch('shop')}"
    env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:token_url] = token_url
  }
end
```