# Accessing Litmus API results in an SSL error. Any way to resolve it?

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, httparty

Summary: When I connect to Litmus via the [gem](https://github.com/mattfawcett/litmus), I get the following error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 unrecognized name
```

Accessing the api via curl with the same credentials works OK.

I found this solution for a similar error: [SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A - Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223691/ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv2-v3-read-server-hello-a-fara)

Which recommends changing the SSL options in oauth:

```
ssl_options[:version] = :TLSv1
```

Is there a way to set the ssl options for Litmus? Is there another possible workaround?

Here's the full trace:

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Litmus::Base.new("xxx.litmus.com", "yyy@yyy.com", "zzz", true)
 => #<Litmus::Base:0x007fad4a66dc68> 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > Litmus::EmailTest.list
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 unrecognized name
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:93:in `perform'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:521:in `perform_request'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:457:in `get'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/litmus-0.3.0/lib/litmus/test.rb:4:in `list'
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/litmus-0.3.0/lib/litmus/email_test.rb:4:in `list'
  from (irb):3
  from /Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It sounds like the server requires a servername through SNI. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it with Ruby. You can verify it with OpenSSL's `s_client`: `openssl s_client -tls1 -connect www.litmus.com:443 -servername litmus.com`. If it succeeds, then omit `-servername`. `-servername` sends the SNI extension.

Comment: `Litmus::EmailTest...` - also, email can be different than HTTPS. With some email protocols, you establish a TCP connection and then enable TLS with `STARTTLS` extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you'll need to patch [base.rb's](https://github.com/mattfawcett/litmus/blob/master/lib/litmus/base.rb) initialize method to accept an ssl version parameter, and then add something like this to the method:

```
def initialize(company, username, password, ssl = false, ssl_version)
  protocol = ssl ? 'https' : 'http'
  self.class.base_uri "#{protocol}://#{company}.litmus.com"
  self.class.basic_auth(username, password)
  self.class.ssl_version = ssl_version # <=
end
```

Then call it like:

```
Litmus::Base.new("xxx.litmus.com", "yyy@yyy.com", "zzz", true, :TLSv1)
```

Hope that helps, I did notice you posted an issue of the same topic in their Github repo. Perhaps you can fork & create a pull request.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting `undefined method 'ssl_version=' for Litmus::Base:Class (NoMethodError)` which is strange because HTTParty does expose the `ssl_version=` method. Any ideas?

Comment: hrm, that is indeed strange, just for giggles, try reverting what you changed, and just add the following `ssl_version = :TLSv1` after the `include HTTParty` statement in base.rb (outside of the initialize method).

Comment: OK, assigning SSL version works, but without the `=`, both on the class and in initialize. Unfortunately, still an SSL error: `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: tlsv1 unrecognized name (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

Comment: I'm afraid I may not be of more assistance, however I found the following question that may be somehow related to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369962/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-unknown-state-unkn . Maybe that will help point you in the right direction?

Comment: If that doesn't help, I'll delete my answer

Comment: Please do not delete your answer, it is relevant to "how to provide ssl_version" part. Yet, I will hold off with accepthing an answer as this turned out to not resolve the error.