# Faraday::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read se rver hello A on rails and google drive gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, google-drive-realtime-api

I am having an issue on windows and rails using the "google-drive-ruby" gem, When I try to do the "On behalf of you" authorization, after initializing config.json and running session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_config("config.json") in console, a URL is given to me where a permit the use of my google drive and google docs and in response google gives me a code that I copy and paste in my console, what is expected is that my config.json must be rewritten but instead of that I am having the following error.

Faraday::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read se
rver hello A

Does anybody have the answer to this issue?, my ruby version is ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25) [x64-mingw32] and my OpenSSL version on ruby is OpenSSL 1.0.0o 15 Oct 2014

Answer (score 0):

[Faraday Error Connection Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223691/ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv2-v3-read-server-hello-a-fara#23370905)

As described in this post the solution was found by changing the `ssl version`. If this is not the correct solution there is also a github discussion which is good and show a couple of solutions.

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/515

Discussions on google groups

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/02rwXWi5NoM

Same bug for windows
https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/issues/239

Comment: Oh I tried the first one but the command openssl s_client -showcerts -connect rubygems.org:httpsCONNECTED(00000003)

Comment: Oh I tried the first one but the command "openssl s_client -showcerts -connect rubygems.org:httpsCONNECTED(00000003)" like they suggest but that command does not work in my command line, The second one I tried installing the HTTP gem but not luck and the third one is a not closed discussion where I have already asked about that issue lol, I am the last entry in that discussion. I think is just an issue of my OpenSSl with google at the moment they communicate because I can install any other gem and there is not problem with that. I have already tried changing plenty cacerts.pem and cacert.pem